# ADX export creating multiple small files

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am using ADX V3 engine.

I have the following external table definition that I am exporting data to:-

```
.create-or-alter external table <external_table_name>
(
field1:string,
field2:dynamic,
partitiontime:datetime) 
kind=adl
partition by (partitiontime:datetime = bin(partitiontime, 1h)) 
pathformat = (datetime_pattern("yyyy/MM/dd/HH",partitiontime))
dataformat=parquet
( 
   h@'abfss://mycontainer@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/mydir;<storagekey>'
)
```

The export command goes as:-

```
.export async to table <external_table_name> with (useNativeParquetWriter=true) 
<| some_custom_function(datetime(2023-02-22T22:38:00Z),1h) | extend partitiontime=ingestion_time()
```

It's creating multiple (21) small files, total size of all the files is hardly 1MB. All the files belong to the same hourly window , so they are going to the same directory , then why is there need for export to create so many small files? I would ideally like to have it create a single file unless the single file reaches certain threshold (e.g. 100MB which is default as per the documentation). Why it's not following the default 100MB threshold rule? I even tried exporting without specifying useNativeParquetWriter=true (i.e. defaulting it to false) , but there is no change in this behavior, it produces same number of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.export` commands, by default, export the data in distributed manner - so that there are N different files being written to concurrently.

Depending on how many nodes/cores/shards participate in the query part of the `.export` command:

- On one hand, this can significantly improve the throughput of writing the data to the destination.
- On the other hand, this can result with more smaller files.

If you want to have fewer & larger files, at the potential cost of much worse throughput), you can specify `distribution` = `single` (or `distributed` = `false`).

See documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/export-data-to-an-external-table (*specifically: the section named "**Number of files**"*)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/export-data-to-storage